# Storage images not found

Tags: php, laravel, symlink, laravel-5.6

I have a Laravel 5.6 application which runs on a server that hosts several php 5.6 applications with cakephp, I added some configuration for it to serve the Laravel 5.6 one with PHP 7.1 and it is working now, however, the symlink from storage is not working. I've searched about this and have tried several solutions, none of them worked.

```
 'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
],
```

This being my config/filesystems
[symlink showing on cbash with > ls -n public/storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xuUK.png)
[image]

I tried removing the symlink and creating it with the command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

as well as creating it with

```
ln -s storage/app/public public/storage/app/public
```

but haven't been succesful.
What could possibly be wrong? 
If I go and check an image in public/img it works
https://inversionistas.grupoidesa.com/img/avatar.png
but the storage link doesn't, I've tried several times with different configurations and urls like

```
https://inversionistas.grupoidesa.com/storage/comp.pdf
https://inversionistas.grupoidesa.com/storage/app/public/comp.pdf
https://inversionistas.grupoidesa.com/public/comp.pdf
```

etc but none has worked.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[Yes, the file exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKVqT.png)

[image]

[These are the permitions of the folder, the permision were given with chmod recursively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nbr4.png)

Comment: Check the permissions on the directory itself.

Comment: Are you sure comp.pdf exists in your storage/public folder?

Comment: @khartnett I have updated the question, check the attached images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make web server follow symbolic links
For apache web server add

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
.... 
</Directory>
....
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I actually found it myself before I saw the answer but yes, according to the documentation, a more secure way is  SymLinksIfOwnerMatch  which is the one I had configured and somehow, didn't work.